# Add custom link to top links Magento

Tags: php, xml, magento, header, frontend

Can I add custom link, like for instance http://google.com/ to this code:

```
<reference name="top.links">
    <action method="addLink" translate="label title" >
        <label>Your Label</label>
        <url ....../>
        <title>Your Title</title>
        <prepare/>
        <urlParams/>
        <position>100</position>
    </action>
</reference>
```

This code is from customer.xml from my theme in Magento

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. Add this code in your theme's local.xml, under `<reference name="top.links">`

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label title">
    <label>Google</label>
    <url>http://google.co.in</url>
    <title>Google</title>
    <prepare/>
    <urlParams/>
    <position>80</position>
    <aParams>
        <target>_blank</target>
    </aParams>
</action>
```

P.S: `<target>` is added to open link in new tab.

Comment: I have tested the code you gave me but it doesn't work, returned me an 404 error

Comment: What is the you are hitting ? Do you see element in your top link ? if yes, then check the <href> tag. It is tested code.